# PDF content logic manipulation

Tags: javascript, pdf, logic

Pdf content should always have two div on one page. Only if the content of div is to long, then there can be one div per page, but on next page, it should again be two, again, if the content allows. But that is the rule, show two content, one if content is to long. So I started to work with the javascript, to check the elements height.

```
let attributeDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("attributeDiv");

for(var i = 0; i < attributeDivs.length; i++) {

    var twoElementsOffsetHeight = attributeDivs[i].offsetHeight + attributeDivs[i + 1].offsetHeight;


    if (twoElementsOffsetHeight > 550) {
        attributeDivs[i].style.pageBreakAfter = "always";
    }
}
```

What this does is check if the two contents are to long, then it will do the page break on the first content.
But the problem is that content can be so small, that 4 of them are smaller then 550. So this is not good. Then I tried to break every second content to see can I work something with that:

```
for(var i = 0; i < attributeDivs.length; i++) {

    var twoElementsOffsetHeight = attributeDivs[i].offsetHeight + attributeDivs[i + 1].offsetHeight;


    if (i % 2) {
        attributeDivs[i].style.pageBreakAfter = "always";
    }
}
```

But then is the problem if the first is to long, it will break the content on the second page, even if it is small one.

Also, I noticed now that javascript does not calculate the hole element if the content goes on the second page. Only the content on the one page get offsetHeight.

How to approach this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use a counter like this:

```
let attributeDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("attributeDiv");
var counter = 0; // <--- this is new

for(var i = 0; i < attributeDivs.length; i++) {

    var twoElementsOffsetHeight = attributeDivs[i].offsetHeight + attributeDivs[i + 1].offsetHeight;

    counter += 1; // <--- this is new

    if (twoElementsOffsetHeight > 550) {
        attributeDivs[i].style.pageBreakAfter = "always";
        counter = 0; // <--- this is new
    }else if(counter == 2) // <--- this is new
    {
      attributeDivs[i].style.pageBreakAfter = "always";
      counter = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and I will use your approach for sure. The only doubt that I have is, if the content of one div goes to another page, offsetHeight does not calculate it. It only calculates the content of the one page. Is there some way that I can calculate the div content if it goes to another page? I mean I still can use your solution and tell the client to fit the content to one page, but If you have some way how to do it, I would make this solution even more flexible. Again thank you a lot!

Comment: Thank's for accepting the answer. if i understand you correct, what you wanna do is splitting up elements larger than 550 so that if you have divs for example (100,650,320) it becomes (100,550,100,320). If this doesn't help i would suggest that you open a new question ...